# vb.net Using regex.Replace gives me overload resolution failed error

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to remove img files from webbrowser1 control.

This is what I did.

```
 Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted

        Dim origHTML As String
        origHTML = WebBrowser1.DocumentText
        Dim newHTML As String
        Dim regex As String = "<img.*/>"
        newHTML = regex.Replace(origHTML, regex, "", RegexOptions.Multiline)
        WebBrowser1.DocumentText = newHTML

        WebBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True

    End Sub
```

I'm getting 'Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Replace' accepts this number of arguments' error.
Any advice, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using String's Replace, not the Regex object's Replace.

Try this:

```
Dim pattern As String = "<img.*/>"
newHTML = Regex.Replace(origHTML, pattern, "", RegexOptions.Multiline)
```

I'm not sure if that Regex pattern will work though, but that should fix the overload error.

Comment: Thank you. The overload error is fixed but regex pattern isn't working.

Comment: Try `<img\b[^>]*>` as the pattern. Regex isn't a skill of mine but there are plenty of patterns in Google to try. The issues are finding one that matches with/without a closing tag, multiline or single, case sensitivity etc. but this one should get you started. See http://regexadvice.com/forums/permalink/32770/34262/ShowThread.aspx#34262